# Limit number of rows in CSS grid

Tags: javascript, angular, css, css-grid

Good morning,

I'm currently trying to implement an image gallery based upon the new CSS grid. In detail, I only want to display one row initially and let the user then expand more and more images by clicking a *Show more* button.

This is how it looks so far: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-96bdii?file=src%2Fapp%2Fgallery.component.ts

Now, my problem is that real-world images (instead of colored *divs*) need more time to be loaded completely. Therefore, the `ngViewAfterInit` *hack*  doesn't work as the total width is not correct at the time `ngViewAfterInit` is called. Also, the total width is automatically calculated by a flexbox layout so I essentially don't know it (early).

Could you imagine a better (working) solution that perhaps uses CSS grid techniques I'm not aware of to limit the number of rows to one?

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could retrieve your images programmatically like this:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
  //retrieve this.width
}
img.src = 'http://www.example.com/image.gif';
```

Then use it to compute the right width and `photosPerRow`